# Mazda 3 (1.6 L 4EAT - BKL3 Z6) Vacuum Line for Sea Foam

Tags: mazda-3, vacuum-hoses

I have heard a lot about `Sea Foam` and would like to try out in my `mazda 3 2010`. I am planning to put a can in the `Gas Tank`, half a can in the `Crank Case` and remaining half into the intake through `vacuum line`.
Unfortunately I am not very sure about the vacuum line, please help me if the following is the Vacuum line which can be used for the same. My earlier plan was to use the `Sea Foam spray` through `throttle` but unfortunately `spray` is not available in the Philippines (only motor treatment is available)
[image]

PS: Most of the videos or online instruction for Mazda is for 2.0L or 2.3L engines, I would like to confirm the same for 1.6L engine

Comment: Your picture is too dark, I can't really tell from it. Can you post a picture which is brighter in the upper right hand corner?

Answer (score 4):

I would not use the vacuum line shown in your picture. The reason being, it looks to be plumbed off of only one intake runner (supporting a single cylinder). While this would work good for a vacuum source, it won't do for a SeaFoam treatment. If you were to use this, you'd only be supplying the SeaFoam to a single cylinder and not to all of them. You need a vacuum source which is common to the plenum (large area just before the intake runners). This will disburse the SeaFoam throughout. If this isn't available, you'd need an alternative method, such as using the engine treatment through the throttle body (as you mentioned), but using some sort of makeshift spraying apparatus to inject it into the intake stream.

For a little more insight into SeaFoam, you can read [this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/15663/4152).

Answer (score 4):

You could try using a device like the one below to spray into the throttle body. It uses compressed air rather than aerosol propellants, and so is safer for the environment and likely available in your country.

[image]

Comment: Can you safely refill this container with air using a compressor?

Comment: @LateralTerminal Yep! That black rubber bit on the top is covering a schrader valve you can use to recharge it, and you can unscrew that entire plug to fill it with liquid.

Comment: Goodbye canned air from the store! You're never getting another penny out of me! I'm going to use this to clean out everything now.

Answer (score 0):

I finished `sea foaming` today and pretty much followed the suggestions mentioned above. Yes for a 1.6L engine the vacuum line shown above is through only 1 cylinder and may not properly disburse the liquid to all the cylinders.

The `Vaper Spot Spray` is an excellent tool and similar ones are available on `Ali Express`, which are smaller in size but built for similar purpose.

I took the suggestion to next level and ended up buying a `200 ML syringe` with a `extended pipe`, inserted it into throttle body and followed the regular procedure. Kind of manual process and had to repeat it twice for half a can of `SeaFoam` (200ML and 100 ML) but it was pretty much what I had at my disposal and did the work as expected. Just be slow and gentle with the syringe to avoid injecting too much `sea foam` at one time.

Final Verdict - Car feels much more responsive, smoother and lighter. Transmission shift time from 1st to 2nd and to 3rd has significantly improved.