# Spark plug analysis [Photo]

Tags: nissan, sparkplugs

I noticed some performance issues while accelerating and today, I decided to pull my spark plugs out and check their condition.

This is a Nissan car with 2L NEO Direct Injection engine and they have used NGK LFR5AQP spark plugs in it.

Vehicle has nearly 111,000Km on it and these are the original spark plugs. It's time to replace them but, what do you guys think about them? Any ideas about the mixture?

[image: NGK LFR5AQP]
[image: NGK LFR5AQP]

Comment: Go to NGK as those are the plugs you have : see here : https://www.ngksparkplugs.com/about-ngk/faqs/spark-plug-faqs/how-do-i-read-a-spark-plug.  A bit of research....

Comment: What is the year/model of the your Nissan?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 It's a Nissan Sylphy 2002. I cleaned the MAF and performance issue seems to be solved. According to my plugs, my engine is not running rich or lean I think?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Check below for follow-up ...**

Two things:

1. You shouldn't need to replace your plugs until ~161k KMs (~100k miles). 11,000 kms means these plugs are about broke in, not ready for replacement.
2. These plugs look fairly healthy. I'm not seeing any carbon buildup; they don't look burnt; the electrodes look in good shape.

If you're having a performance issue with the car, **I'd suggest you look elsewhere for your performance issue**. While replacing the plugs won't hurt anything, at 11,000km you're just wasting money.

### FOLLOW UP

Your plugs look in really good shape. If rich, they'd be black and possibly wet looking. If running lean, they'd be *very* tan in color and possibly have degraded electrodes and bubbling on the porcelain. If these are the original plugs (assuming what you said is correct), I'd change out these plugs with new and not think a second about it. It may be time to replace the O2 sensors if that hasn't been done since new. If you've cleaned the MAF and throttle body, you should be in pretty good shape. You may also want to ensure the PCV is cleaned and is doing its thing. You may want to run some fuel injector cleaner (heavy duty stuff like BG-44k if available, or give it a [SeaFoam treatment](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/15663/4152)).

Comment: Sorry. It's my mistake. It's actually 111,000km and not 11,000

Comment: @madhushankarox - check the follow up edits :o)

Comment: I cleaned the PCV valve and I'm thinking to relace it later. EGR valve and throttle body also cleaned. Bank 2 O2 sensor also replaced. Everything is in good shape. But, I have no idea about the timing chain. Whether it's stretched or not.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the answers I have seen- plugs look good. However ,plugs can look okay and have some spark leakage deep in the body ; between the steel body and defects in the porcelain  insulator. So I would change at 100K miles ( although I have gone to 120 K with no problems). And , since you have done all the work, I would just go ahead and replace these plugs for the minor cost ( although it is likely too late when you read this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I really appreciate. I have a spear set of Denso Iridium plugs. I tired them and they are doing good. But I need to get this 4 probg plugs.